# Directed Acyclic Graph - root and leaf node terminology

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I have found conflicting terminology regarding how to label nodes in directed acyclic graphs. Specifically, I am looking for a definition of root and leaf nodes (preferably something to cite). For example, can someone label which nodes in the following graph are root nodes and which are leaf nodes?

[image: example]

Comment: Conflicting examples:
1) http://ericsink.com/vcbe/html/directed_acyclic_graphs.html
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005850/directed-acyclic-graph-with-multi-parent-nodes

Comment: I think the terms "root" and "leaf" are hold-overs from tree graphs. How you define them depends on how you interpret the arrows, e.g. "depends on" vs. "has influence on". Generally, if there is a way to interpret the graph chronologically, the leaf is the node that is later in time (e.g. node/version 6 in your first example; I am not sure if example 2 has a time aspect). For DAGs, I prefer the terminology **source** and **sink** instead of root and leaf, as the former terms are unambiguously defined in terms of the direction of the edges.

Comment: What @Marconius said, I have frequently seen _source_ and _sink_ used in this context. Although, don't forget to define it, just to be clear.